# Ruby on Rails Approve / Reject buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My form is simple:

```
    <%= form_for(@shop, remote: true, data: { confirm: "You sure?"}) do |fa| %>
      <%= fa.hidden_field :status, :value => 1 %>
      <%= fa.submit "Approve", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form_for(@shop, remote: true, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }) do |fr| %>
      <%= fr.hidden_field :status, :value => 2 %>
      <%= fr.submit "Reject", class: "btn btn-large btn-danger" %>
    <% end %>
```

I want to update an attribute `status` of `@shop`. Pressing "Approve" should set it to 1, "Reject" - to 2 respectively. But now nothing happens when I click the buttons (except confirmation). I know I don't have something important and fundamental in my code, but I can't figure out what.

Also, is there a way to write everything in one form_for? Like

```
<%= form_for(@shop, remote: true, data: { confirm: "You sure?"}) do |fa| %>
  <%= fa.hidden_field :status_a, :value => 1 %>
  <%= fa.hidden_field :status_r, :value => 2 %>
  <%= fa.submit "Approve", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
  <%= fa.submit "Reject", class: "btn btn-large btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

**PS: Shop controller** has:

```
  def update
    if @shop.update_attributes(shop_params)
      flash[:success] = "Shop updated"
      redirect_to @shop
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end
.
.
  private

    def shop_params       
       params.require(:shop).permit(:title, :rating, :pic, :status,
                                    address_attributes: [:country, :state, :city, :street])
    end
```

**Server log** when pressing Approve button:

```
Started PATCH "/shops/64" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-12 12:52:36 +0400
Processing by ShopsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "shop"=>{"status"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Approve", "id"=>"64"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '5927a9415e68e7b293f8d1e24a709961bc260195' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/shops_controller.rb:35:in `update'


  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb (66.5ms)
```

35th line in ShopsController is

```
if @shop.update_attributes(shop_params)
```

Comment: Yes,it is possible to combine everything in to one `form`.Can you post your `shop_params` method?

Comment: Pavan, sure, edited the controller!

Comment: Is `status` is a `boolean datatype attribute`?

Comment: No, it's integer.     `validates  :status, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 2 }`

Comment: Can you post the `server log` generated?

Comment: you can use link_to to create 2 new links and add the 'btn' class to make it look like a button(if you are using bootstrap). And send an additional parameter (accepted/rejected) through the link. the link should map to a controller action which will update the status of the object with the received parameter. if you dont want to refresh the page then add the 'remote: true' option to the link_to method.

Comment: Pavan, added server log when I press 'Approve'.

Comment: Your log shows an error `NoMethodError (undefined method update_attributes' for nil:NilClass)`. Have you defined `@shop` variable in your controller for the `update` method?

Comment: Pavan, thanks, that definitely helped me. I added `@shop = Shop.find(params[:id])` in update action and now everything works! Post it as an answer, and I'll approve it!

Comment: Santosh has already posted it as answer.Accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch the `Shop` object before updating it's attributes

```
def update
  @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
  if @shop.update_attributes(shop_params)
    ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can assign your hidden input value at your button's onclick action like this:

```
<%= form_for(@shop, remote: true, data: { confirm: "You sure?"}) do |fa| %>
  <%= fa.hidden_field :status, :value => 1 %>
  <%= fa.submit "Approve", class: "btn btn-large btn-success", onclick: "shop_status.value = '1'" %>
  <%= fa.submit "Reject", class: "btn btn-large btn-danger", onclick: "shop_status.value = '2'" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jaugar! It's close, but still there's a problem, because clicking on a button doesn't change status.

Comment: You should see the hidden_field's source code of the html rails generated. I think you can try `onclick: "shop_status.value = '1'"` to see if it works.